# Only 6 out of 8 16-bit data were written to the STM32 Flash Memory

Tags: arm, stm32, microcontroller, stm32f4, flash-memory

I am trying to write 8 pieces of 16-bit data into the STM32F410 flash memory, particularly the 4th sector starting at address 0x0801_1000. The only initialization that I did involves changing the `FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_3WS;` because the HCLK is at 100MHz, and the input voltage should be at around 3.3V.

Here is the code I have so far for writing all the data into the Flash Memory:

```
/* Each segment will store 16-bit data */
#define BASE_ADDRESS            ((uint32_t)0x8011000)

#define ADDRESS_1               ((uint32_t)BASE_ADDRESS)
#define ADDRESS_2               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_1 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_3               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_2 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_4               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_3 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_5               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_4 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_6               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_5 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_7               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_6 + 0x04)
#define ADDRESS_8               ((uint32_t)ADDRESS_7 + 0x04)


void FLASH_MassWrite(void)
{
    /* Stop timer interrupts */
    HAL_LPTIM_Counter_Stop_IT(&hlptim1);
    
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP|FLASH_FLAG_OPERR|FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR|FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR|FLASH_FLAG_PGSERR);
    FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_4, VOLTAGE_RANGE_4);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_1, (uint16_t)0xABCD);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_2, (uint16_t)0x1234);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_3, (uint16_t)0x5678);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_4, (uint16_t)0x4321);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_5, (uint16_t)0x8765);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_6, (uint16_t)0xFEDC);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_7, (uint16_t)0xBA98);
    HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, ADDRESS_8, (uint16_t)0xAABB);
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    
    /* Resume timer interrupts */
    HAL_LPTIM_Counter_Start_IT(&hlptim1, 199);          
}
```

The above method does not work properly for me as the STM32F410 fail to write into the first two addresses (at 0x8011000 and 0x8011004). If I change the address so that it starts writing to 0x8011008 instead, the first 3 16-bit data is not written properly instead. I also tried changing it to `FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD` so that it writes in 16-bit blocks, but it didn't make any difference.

Here is the screenshot containing the contents of my memory region. Note that the last 6 entries of 16-bit data were properly written in the correct order:

[image: Flash Memory Contents]

Here is the screenshot showing the Flash Status Register:

[image: Flash Status Register]

*What step am I missing to reliably write data into the STM32 Flash Memory?* I am experimenting writing multiple data at once because I plan on storing some amount of data. I was thinking that if I plan on storing a few bytes of data, I might need to store all of them at once because a Mass Erase is required prior to writing data to a certain address of Sector 4 of the Flash Memory, which would mean erasing previously stored/written/saved data on a different address.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the return values of the `HAL_FLASH_*()` functions.

Comment: @kkrambo I tried checking the return values and they all seem to return `HAL_OK`. I looked through the STM32Cube examples and I noticed that `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&pEraseInit, &SectorError)` was used instead of `FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_4, VOLTAGE_RANGE_4)`. I tried swapping it out and writing to the Flash memory works when using `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase()` to wipe the Flash memory.